# Testing all cases regarding the return value of scanf

Tags: c, scanf

With the code below, if I enter 1 string and ctrl-D, it will print did not scan in two words and exit. However if I enter 3 or more strings it takes the first two and throws away the rest. How can I account for this - to make an exit happen if more than two strings are entered?

```
int scan_count = 0;

printf("Enter two strings: \n");

scan_count = (scanf("%s %s", first_word, second_word));
if (scan_count != 2)
{
    printf("Did not scan in two words successfully, exiting.\n");
    exit(2);
}
```

Comment: Read a whole line with `fgets` and then parse it yourself to make sure it contains exactly two words.

Comment: Check the input bufer for non-whitespace character after scanf() returns

Comment: @PaulR If you make it a full answer I can give full credit :)!

Comment: @Finlandia_C you should check `scanf` for errors before you assign its result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common usage is to try to read one string more:

```
char dummy[2];
scan_count = (scanf("%s %s %1s", first_word, second_word, dummy));
```

But this would only work if you terminate input with Ctrl-D. If you want to know if a **line** contains exactly 2 words, you must first get the line with `fgets` and then split it with `sscanf`:

```
char line[SIZE], dummy[2];
printf("Enter two strings: \n");
cr = fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin); /* should test cr againt NULL - omitted for brievety */
if (strchr(line, '\n') == NULL) {
    ...  /* no EOL : line too long*/
}
scan_count = (sscanf("%s %s %1s", first_word, second_word, dummy));
if (scan_count != 2) ...
```

Comment: 1) `(strchr(line, '\n') == NULL)` is OK(not too long) on last line and can occur on rare cases when `fgets()` read a null character.  2) certainly you meant `scan_count = sscanf(line, "%s ...`

Answer (score 0):

I know that is ugly but it does the job:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int checkString(char *s1, char *s2){
    int c=0,i = 0,j=0,count1 = 0,count2 = 0,res = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF){
        s1[i++] = (char) c;
        if(c ==' '){
            count1++;
        }
    }
    s1[i]='\0';

    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF){
        s2[j++] = (char) c;
        if(c ==' '){
            count2++;
        }
    }
    s2[j]='\0';

    if((strlen(s1) == 0) || (strlen(s2) == 0)){
        return res = 0;
    }else if((count1 + count2) == 0){
        res = 2;
    }

    return  res;
}

int main(void){
    char first_word[50];
    char second_word[50];
    int scan_count = 0;

    printf("Enter any string : ");
    if ((scan_count = checkString(first_word,second_word)) != 2){
        printf("Did not scan in two words successfully, exiting.\n");
        exit(2);
    }else{
        printf("You typed two strings.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output1:

> ```
> Enter any string : michael jackson
> michael
> Did not scan in two words successfully, exiting.
> ```

Output2:

> ```
> Enter any string : Michael
> Jackson
> You typed two strings.
> ```